# Setting initial state in component to Redux store

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

I'm using template project from VS (React + Redux + TS) and I don't know exactly how to set component state because when i do that in constructor, it omitting that.

It looks like the component have two states (?): own, and from store. I don't understand this mechanism...

```
class Nodes extends React.Component<{ handleClick: () => void, nodes: NodeProps[], force: any}, NodeStore.NodeState>{

    constructor(props: any){
        super(props);

        this.state = {name: "test"}; //change 'in' component state
    }

    render(){
        const nodes = this.props.nodes.map((node: NodeProps, index: number) => {
            return <Node key={index} node={node} onClick={this.handleClick} />;
            });

        return (
            <g className="nodes">
            {nodes}
            TestName: {this.state.name} // thats always "test", but after click should be "testaddedstring" 
            </g>
        );
    }

    private handleClick =() => {
        this.props.handleClick();
        alert("clicked!");
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state: ApplicationState) => {
    return {
        name: state.node.name // state from store not from component
    }
};

const mapDispatchToProps = {
    handleClick: NodeStore.actionCreators.changeName
};

export default connect<any, typeof NodeStore.actionCreators, any>(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(Nodes);
```

This is the index.ts file with store definitions:

```
export interface ApplicationState {

    node: Node.NodeState; 
}

export const reducers = {
    node: Node.reducer
};

export interface AppThunkAction<TAction> {
    (dispatch: (action: TAction) => void, getState: () => ApplicationState): void;
}
```

and action reducer:

```
export interface NodeState {
    name: string;
}

interface ChangeNameAction {type: 'CHANGE_NAME'}

export const actionCreators = {
    changeName: () => <ChangeNameAction>{ type: 'CHANGE_NAME' }
}

export const reducer: Reducer<NodeState> = (state: NodeState, action: ChangeNameAction) => {
    if (action.type === 'CHANGE_NAME'){
        return { name: state.name + "addedstring"};
    }

    return state || {name: "default name"};
};
```

What is missed?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. The component can have local state, and you have the store which can be looked at as a global state, since it can be accessed from wherever in your application. redux-connect attaches the stores properties and puts them into your component as props and can then be accessed by using this.props.foo

Answer (score 0):

`mapStateToProps()` passes props into your component not state.

Therefore, when you call `this.props.handleClick()`, `name`, now equal to "testaddedstring", will be passed into `Nodes` props and can be accessed inside the component as `this.props.name`. However, `this.state.name` is unaffected. If you want to update the `this.state.name` you need to do so inside `componentWillReceiveProps()`. Something like this:

```
interface Props {
    force: any;
    handleClick: () => void; 
    name: string;
    nodes: NodeProps[]; 
}

class Nodes extends React.Component<Props, NodeStore.NodeState> {

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps: Props, nextState: NodeStore.NodeState): void {
        this.setState({ name: nextProps.name });
    }

    ...

}
```

Either that or you use `this.props.name` instead of `this.state.name` in `render()`. As you have it now, there is no need to put `name` in the component state because you aren't editing it inside the component. So you could just remove your constructor altogether.